# Yii framework add defer in script tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

How to add defer in script tag? I using this `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/js/jquery.js');`

And I try to change to `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/js/jquery.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD,array('defer'=>'defer'));`

or 
`Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/js/jquery.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD,array('id'=>'defer'));`

is not work. I didn't know how to do. Please help.

Comment: Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/js/jquery.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD,array('defer'=>'true')); try this.

Comment: still not work, do you have other way?

Answer (score 5):

You can provide the option such as

```
$this->registerJsFile('https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton',['position' => View::POS_END, 'async'=>true, 'defer'=>true]);
```

To add interanl js

```
  $this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl .'/your_js_path',['position' => View::POS_END, 'async'=>true, 'defer'=>true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

1. Check the function registerScriptFile() in **CClientScript.php** , if the param ***htmlOptions*** does not exist, replace 2 files bellow in your source from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii

   - [CClientScript.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CClientScript.php)
   - [CHtml.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php)
2. Comment line `'defer'=>1` of function `renderAttributes()` in file
   **CHtml.php**
3. Add this line: 
   Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->get‌​BaseUrl().'/js/jquer‌​y.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD, array('defer'=> ''));

Comment: but I need to add the defer, something like this `<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>`